# Get SWF file information using PHP (or javascript)

Tags: php, flash

For one of my projects I would like to use PHP to read an SWF file on the server and get the dimensions of the stage of the SWF. So, the SWF file is not yet embedded in the page. Does anybody know if this is possible and which route I should take?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/getimagesize) , it works perfectly with swf files.

Comment: @codeburger & @karim79 getImageSize indeed does the job! After searching the net I expected a more difficult solution than that! Using getimagesize is definitely not the first search result I've encountered before asking here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

See this (SWF Header Parser Class - licensed under LGPL):

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1653.html

The website says this:

> This class is meant to parse the
>   header of Shockwave Flash animation
>   files (.swf) to extract metadata
>   information like the width and height
>   of animation, compression status and
>   uncompressed size, frame rate and
>   total number of frames.
>
> This class parses Flash files using
>   only PHP code, so no special extension
>   is necessary.
>
> Supports both, compressed and
>   uncompressed SWF Flash movies

Comment: Okay, thanks Karim79 that looks quite usefull! Let's implement now.

Comment: @tvgemert - if getimagesize does it, as codeburger suggested, then *definately* go with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a solution to getimagesize() on .SWF files stored in the database, here is a blob-data-as-file-stream wrapper I wrote. Tested on PHP 5.3.10.

http://pastebin.com/6uriJMZv